# I am not sure what is wrong with my quick select method

Tags: java

So I tried to write a code to select kth smallest element in a given input `integer` array using `quick sort`, but for some reason as you can see in the code below,

```
public static int partition(int[] input, int first, int end) {
    int pivot = input[(first + end)/2];
    int i = first - 1;
    int j = end + 1;

    while (true) {

      do {
        i++;
      } while (input[i] < pivot);

      do {
        j--;
      } while (input[j] > pivot);

      if (i < j)
        swap(input, i, j);
      else
        return j;
    }
  }

  public static void swap(int[] input, int i, int j){
    int temp = input[i];
    input[i] = input[j];
    input[j] = temp;
  }

  public static int select(int[] input, int k){
    return mySelect(input, 0, input.length-1, k);
  }

  public static int mySelect(int[] input, int left, int right, int k){ 
    // If k is smaller than number of elements in array 
    if (k > 0 && k <= right - left + 1) { 

      int pos = partition(input, left, right); 

      if (pos - left == k - 1) 
        return input[pos]; 

      // If position is larger, recursive call on the left subarray 
      if (pos - left > k - 1)  
        return mySelect(input, left, pos-1, k); 

      // if smaller, recursive call on the right subarray 
      return mySelect(input, pos+1, right, k-pos+left-1); 
    } 

    System.out.println("Invalid k value");
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
    test2 = new int[]{99, 44, 77, 22, 55, 66, 11, 88, 33};
    int[] test2 = new int[]{99, 44, 77, 22, 55, 66, 11, 88, 33};
    //testing for selecting kth min 
    System.out.println("The 1st smallest : " + select(test2, 1));
    System.out.println("The 2nd smallest : " + select(test2, 2));
    System.out.println("The 3rd smallest : " + select(test2, 3));
    System.out.println("The 4th smallest : " + select(test2, 4));
    System.out.println("The 6th smallest : " + select(test2, 6));
    System.out.println("The 9th smallest : " + select(test2, 9)); 
    }
```

but my **1st smallest element appears 22, 2nd smallest returns 11, while others values are normal.** 
can someone please help me find what is the mistake I made?

Comment: What have you done to debug this code? A hint - it seems that your `select` method doesn't just `select`, it also modified and sorts the array as a side effect. If you change your code to sort the array first, only once, and then select, you stand a better chance to find out where the problem is exactly - give your methods a *single responsibility*, and also give them a name that indicates what the method really does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is in the partition. The `do while` is the culprit here. You are updating the positions before checking the conditions and that's causing the problem with the `last` swap operation.

Update your method to this and you will be good to go

```
public static int partition(int[] input, int first, int end) {
    int pivot = input[(first + end)/2];
    int i = first;
    int j = end;

    while (true) {

      while (input[i] < pivot) {
        i++;
      }

      while (input[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
      }

      if (i < j)
        swap(input, i, j);
      else
        return j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code while I was learning quick sort. The mistake I made was in not realizing that

'left' and 'right' are indices in array whereas,

'pivot' is one of the values stored in array

You can study my code below and determine what's wrong in your understanding of the algorithm!!

```
public class QuickSort
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = {1,5,9,2,7,8,4,2,5,8,9,12,35,21,34,22,1,45}; 

        quickSort(0,nums.length-1,nums);
        //print nums to see if sort is working as expected,omit printing in your case
        print(nums);
        //now you can write code to select kth smallest number from sorted nums here
    }

    /**
     * left and right are indices in array whereas
     * pivot is one of the values stored in array
     */
    static int partition(int left, int right , int pivot, int[] nums)
    {
        int leftIndex = left -1;
        int rightIndex = right;
        int temp = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            while( nums[++leftIndex] < pivot );
            while( rightIndex>0 && nums[--rightIndex] > pivot );

            if( leftIndex >= rightIndex ) break;
            else//swap value at leftIndex and rightIndex
            {
                temp = nums[leftIndex];
                nums[leftIndex]= nums[rightIndex];
                nums[rightIndex] = temp;
            }
        }

        //swap value at leftIndex and initial right index
        temp = nums[leftIndex];
        nums[leftIndex]= nums[right];
        nums[right] = temp;

        return leftIndex;
    }

    static void quickSort( int leftIndex , int rightIndex ,int[] nums)
    {
        if( rightIndex-leftIndex <= 0 ) return;
        else
        {
            int pivot = nums[rightIndex];
            int partitionIndex = partition(leftIndex, rightIndex , pivot,nums);
            quickSort(leftIndex,partitionIndex-1,nums);
            quickSort(partitionIndex+1,rightIndex,nums);
        }
    }

    static void print(int[] nums)
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print(nums[i]+", ");
        }
    }

}
```